# Angular and Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, angular

using Angular 4, I'm trying to post an image from my website on Facebook. Once I paste the URL in FB, I can see the app's title but not an image.  I have the following in my head tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://djangularphil.herokuapp.com/static/ang/assets/images/records/records_lg.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url"  content="https://djangularphil.herokuapp.com/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Musical Memory Lane" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Phase1: Eventually all my record albums will be posted here." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="fb-app-id-went-here" />
```

Way am I doing wrong?  My goal is to have a clickable image on Facebook that when clicked will take use to my web site.

I solved my issue by following [How to post clickable images on Facebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vGuhWSAFeQ)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thanks  - I have all the properties define yet I get this from the FB debugger: Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Comment: Example URL ...?

Comment: https://djangularphil.herokuapp.com/

Comment: That does not contain a single OG meta tag in the HTML the server returns.

Comment: Yes, I see that so what is the trick to getting them in using Angular?

Comment: You need to use some form of pre-rendering, so that your server directly returns the appropriate meta tags for the requested URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153068/discussion-between-phil-o-and-cbroe).